# react-native: Ellipsize text and prevent it from growing past parent

Tags: react-native, layout, flexbox

I have a layout with 4 boxes. I want to maintain the proportions of the boxes and ellipsize the text within when it gets long. This is what it looks like when the text is short:

[image: layout with short text]

But when the text grows, the parent containers grow as well, which ruins the layout:

[image: layout with long text]

I've been able to produce the desired result only when I pass pixel widths to the Text components:

[image: workaround]

What is the proper way to achieve the above result without using pixel values as widths? Here is my code (note that I'm using `Row`, `Box`, and `Text` from `native-base`, but I checked it with plain react-native `View` and `Text` and the result was the same):

```
export default function DayMetadataCard({ metadata, id }) {
    return (
        <Row
            bg="offBlack.400"
            borderBottomLeftRadius={16}
            borderBottomRightRadius={16}
            borderWidth={1}
            borderColor="offBlack.600"
            flex={1}
        >
            <Box width="33%" borderRightWidth={1} borderColor="offBlack.600">
                <Box flex={1} borderColor="offBlack.600" borderBottomWidth={1}>    
                    <Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode="tail" width="121px">
                        short text
                    </Text>
                </Box>
                <Box flex={1}>
                    <Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode="tail" width="121px">
                        short text
                    </Text>
                </Box>
            </Box>
            <Box width="67%">
                <Box flex={1} borderColor="offBlack.600" borderBottomWidth={1}>
                    <Text numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode="tail" width="246px">
                        short text
                    </Text>
                </Box>
                <Box flex={1}>
                    <Text width="246px" numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode="tail">
                        short text
                    </Text>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Row>
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the flex: 1 for the text components?

Comment: @DanielZheng yes — if I replace the pixel widths with flex={1}, the text grows beyond its container and doesn't ellipsize.